# matlab drop 3rd dimension of a array and assign it to a 2d array

Tags: matlab

I have a 3 dimensional array. I want to assign only the first two dimensions to a 2D array.

The array is

A<44,512,3 uint8>

I need to drop the 3 and assign it to a new array B so that B would be

B<44,512 uint8>

I do not know how to proceed. Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which 2D slice of your 3D array do you need? If you want slice #2, you do:

```
B = A(:,:,2);
```

Comment: i think all the three slices contain the same sets of data. But how do i confirm this ?

Comment: @user602774: if `all(all(A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)))` evaluates to `true`, then the first and the second slice are identical. Or you can subtract the first slice of `A` from `A` and test whether all is 0: `all(reshape(bsxfun(@minus,A,A(:,:,1))==0,[],1))`

Comment: i will do all(all(A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,2)))  and then all(all(A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,3))) if both evaluates to 1 then that means all the three columns are same